# How to access the data from the result video? (Cypress)

Tags: node.js, npm, cypress

[image]

I've been using Cypress for a few weeks now and I want to know it is possible to access to the data on the left of the report video, so that I could make more specific report. I couldn't get the data from mochaawesome reports or some other reports that's been suggested on elsewhere.

Comment: Can you specify what exact data you are looking for in reports ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Cypress-terminal-report](https://github.com/archfz/cypress-terminal-report) is a nice plugin that allows you to get reports on the cypress console activity and has nice filtering functions. It appears on the report that are like a long console log.